# How to generate separate test-output folder with timestamp?

Tags: java, maven, selenium-webdriver, testng

I am using TestNG to execute my suite. However, test-output folder gets overwritten after each run. I want to generate a separate test-output folder with timestamp. I am using Maven to build project. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Why do you want to generate separate test-output folder with timestamp?
It creates more duplicate files. Why not to have emailable-report file with timestamp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the default reporters with your own logic. For example, with `SuiteHTMLReporter`:

```
public class MySuiteHTMLReporter extends SuiteHTMLReporter {
  @Override
  void generateReport(java.util.List<XmlSuite> xmlSuites,
                    java.util.List<ISuite> suites,
                    java.lang.String outputDirectory) {
    String timestamp = ...
    super.generateReport(xmlSuites, suites, outputDirectory + "-" + timestamp);
  }
}
```

You can do the same for the others reporters and don't forget to disable them (and enable yours).

Answer (score 0):

You can try and implement a driver(let's say `Driver.java`) in your test which could be used to start your tests(`mainClass` of the test execution).

This class can further have a method to parse the `testNG.xml` file to define the `Test` classes and for each such test you can iterate to execute the following block of statements -

```
TestNG testNG = new TestNG();
// add listeners if needed
testNG.setCommandLineSuite(<yourXmlSuitePath>); // path to testNG.xml file
testNG.setOutputDirectory(<yourOutputDir>); // timestamped directory to specify
testNG.run();
```

---

Or the other approach could be to create a timestamped folder(assume 20170309) in `@AfterAll` method of your suite and configure using [maven-resources-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/copy-resources-mojo.html) to move your resources to the created folder. This can be done in the other way round as well, where you can copy and move previous execution result before `clean` phase and continue with the execution of test to overrite the existing reports.